# PostgreSQL/Psycopg2 upsert syntax to update columns

Tags: postgresql, insert, python, upsert

I want to have Psycopg2 update **col1**, **col2** and **col3** when there is a conflict of id.

In my Python code I have the insert SQL currently as:

```
insert_sql = '''INSERT INTO {t} (id,col1,col2,col3)
        VALUES (%s,%s,NULLIF(%s, 'nan'), NULLIF(%s, 'nan'))
        ON CONFLICT (id)
        DO NOTHING;'''
```

Basically instead of **DO NOTHING** I want to set:

`(col1,col2,col3) = (%s,NULLIF(%s, 'nan'), NULLIF(%s, 'nan'))`

Which ignores inserting ID and updates col1, col2, and col3.
The problem is using `%s` to pass in tuple variables in Python using Psycopg2:

```
cur.execute(insert_sql.format(t='my_table'),(int(id),new_col1,new_col2,new_col3))
```

What is the syntax used to refer to the `%s` corresponding to col1, col2, and col3 to update ON CONFLICT?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `EXCLUDED` keyword to access the values passed to `INSERT`. No need to pass them twice:

```
insert_sql = '''
   INSERT INTO {t} (id,col1, col2, col3)
        VALUES (%s, %s, NULLIF(%s, 'nan'), NULLIF(%s, 'nan'))
        ON CONFLICT (id)
        DO UPDATE SET
            (col1, col2, col3)
            = (EXCLUDED.col1, EXCLUDED.col2, EXCLUDED.col3) ;
'''
```

See examples of use in Postgres documentation about **[`ON CONFLICT`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#INSERT_..._ON_CONFLICT_DO_NOTHING.2FUPDATE_.28.22UPSERT.22.29)**.